# Alpha Vantage asyncio(tickers)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, alpha-vantage

```
from alpha_vantage.async_support.techindicators import TechIndicators
import asyncio

symbols = ['ADI', 'ADMA', 'ADMP', 'ADMS', 'ADNC', 'ADP', 'ADRA', 'ADRD', 'ADRE', 'ADRU', 
'ADSK', 'ADTN', 'ADUS', 'ADVS',
'ADXS', 'ADXSW', 'AEGN', 'AEGR', 'AEHR', 'AEIS', 'AEPI', 'AERI', 'AETI', 'AEY', 'AEZS']
key = open('alphavantageAPI').read()

async def get_data(symbol):
ti = TechIndicators(key, output_format='pandas')
data, _ = await ti.get_sma(symbol=symbol, interval='daily', series_type='close')
await ti.close()
return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [get_data(symbol) for symbol in symbols]
group1 = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
results = loop.run_until_complete(group1)
loop.close()
print(results)
```

I have 25 symbols (tickers). In Alpha Vantage you can receive 5 tickers per a minut.

I need to receive 5 tickers and wait 1 minut and than next 5 tickers. Maybe some one can tell me what I need to add or change in this code. Thank you,

P.S I know about Premium , but this is the task what I need to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sleep` function to wait between 12 and 15 seconds for each request.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

symbols = ['ADI', 'ADMA', 'ADMP', 'ADMS', 'ADNC', ...]

...
for symbol in symbols:
   data = getDataFrom(symbol)
   sleep(np.random.randint(12, 15))
...
```

Comment: This way, the system waits for each new request and not for every 5 requests, it waits one minute. Note that placing a randomizer helps prevent this type of request from being blocked, in case Alpha Vantage decides to block requests from the same IP address spaced at equal times (yes this is possible, but it is not done yet).